# How to indicate progress when using NSSavePanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My macOS application needs to export a file using NSSavePanel, and this file needs complicated progress. Now my way is

```
[mySavePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSModalResponseOK) {
        //complicated progress
    }
}];
```

By this way, when I click "save" button on NSSavePanel, it takes a long time without indicating anything. I want to add something to indicate the progress, but now that NSSavePanel is a modal, so I can't let another window used to indicate progress to showWindow.

Comment: Consider settling up an operation queue and pass it a block to update its progress.

Comment: From the documentation of `beginSheetModalForWindow:`: "Although the completion handler block is called after the user dismisses the panel, the panel sheet may still be visible onscreen. If you need to remove the sheet from the screen—for example, if the completion block displays an alert—first call `[savePanel orderOut:nil]` to close the sheet.".